# AjaxPro and OnTimeOut error

Tags: asp.net, ajaxpro

I am getting the following error on my AjaxPro project:

```
Error: this.onTimeout is not a function
Source: http://localhost:3405/ajaxpro/core.ashx
Line: 407
```

I know it is something to do with the release of AjaxPro, but does any of you have a version which doesn't contain that error? Or how can I correct it?
I have downloaded the latest version from AjaxPro.info, without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please use asynchronous call, like in JavaScript:

```
function getServerTime()
{
  test_Default8.GetServerTime(getServerTime_callback);  // asynchronous call
}

// This method will be called after the method has been executed
// and the result has been sent to the client.

function getServerTime_callback(res)
{
  alert(res.value);
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
http://groups.google.sc/group/ajaxpro/browse_thread/thread/da617d3dc31d65cb